# DisplayPort to DVI adapter: quality concerns

Tags: vga, dvi, displayport

So I searched the local market and was not able to find a DisplayPort to DVI-D cable. My next option is to buy a DP-to-DVI adapter and then attach it to my monitor using a standard DVI-to-DVI cable. My question is: should I go for it? Will this adapter affect image quality in any way? If yes, will the resulting quality still be better than VGA that I am currently using?

(For people interested in knowing, I have got DP and VGA ports in my CPU. Whereas my monitor has DVI-D and VGA ports. You call it fate! :))

Answer (score 1):

DVI (and, for that matter, any digital signal) should offer you a somewhat clearer picture... Though to be honest the change in standards was made to address other issues unrelated to picture quality.

Digital signals can drive higher resolution screens at faster screen refresh rates.

The quality difference between a VGA signal and a DVI-D signal pushing a resolution of 1920x1080@60Hz is going to be negligible (Under 99% of circumstances. You could be in a fringe case where there is a ton of EMI near the video cable in which case DVI-D would provide better picture when it worked at all.), if there is one at all.

That being said, there <s>doesn't appear to be any circuitry for converting between DVI and DP so there won't be any difference between the signals</s> does seem to be some circuitry to convert the signal so it could impact video quality though it is highly unlikely to have a major impact. Aside from things like loose connectors in super cheap products, you should be fine getting any inexpensive adapter (Just stay away from the $0.14 adapters from china).

Comment: This only partly correct. DisplayPort and DVI are not the same and an active adapter is absolutely necessary to convert between the two.

Comment: You are correct. It has passive circuitry in the adapter. Editing answer.

Comment: The image quality will not be affected AT ALL by a DP-DVI or DVI-DP adapter. Though there is some "conversion" circuitry it has no chance for affecting the integrity of the pixel data.